# node.js express - Can't see data from post form in post route

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express, post

Hey i'm trying to do some basic login function in my project with node. But i'm having some trouble with Router. I can't seem to send/display any information in my terminal from the html post form. it only works through POSTMAN for some reason. i also can't add any get route to auth.js then i get the following error when i try to access it:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 
'xxxx/route'

As you can see i've moved the login get route to app.js and it works no problem.

So it boils down to two things:

1. Why can't i get my post form data from login.html and display it with auth.js login post route
2. Why can't i add the login get route to auth.js

This is app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());


app.get("/login", (req, res) => {

    return res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/login.html");
});

const session = require('express-session');
const config = require('./config/config.json');
app.use(session({
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

const limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
    max: 100 // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
});

app.use(limiter);

const authLimiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
    max: 8 // limit each IP to 8 requests per windowMs
});

app.use('/signup', authLimiter);
app.use('/login', authLimiter);


/* Setup Knex with Objection */
const { Model } = require('objection');
const Knex = require('knex');
const knexfile = require('./knexfile.js');
const knex = Knex(knexfile.development);

Model.knex(knex);

const authRoute = require('./routes/auth.js');
const usersRoute = require('./routes/users.js');

app.use(authRoute);
app.use(usersRoute);

const PORT = 3000;

app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log("Server is running on the port", PORT);
})
```

This is my auth.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body)
    let userlogin = {
        username: req.body.uname,
        password: req.body.psw
      }

    console.log(userlogin);

    res.send({ response: userlogin });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the login.html in the public folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body{
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 15%;
        }
        .container{
            padding: 5%;
            margin: 2%;
        }
    </style>
    <title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login site</h1>
    <form  action="/login" method="POST">
        <div class="container">
          <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label><br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" ><br>

          <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label><br>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" ><br><br>

          <button type="submit">Login</button><br><br>
        </div>
    </form> 

    <div>
        <form action="/signup.html">
            <input type="submit" value="signup" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The program suggests that you are using static pages located in public folder. Instead, you need to use templates for using login credentials.

Go for EJS.